# How to show visualization in an Android app

Tags: android, media-player, visualization

I want to show some visualizations such as bar, scope or album art as like in the windows media player according to the song that gets played in an app.

Is it possible to show visualizations  according to the latitude longitude that's getting changed.

Can anybody tell me how I would go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RelativeLayout to overlay a View of your choice over VideoView: [Put any View over a VideoView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118815/put-any-view-over-a-videoview-in-android)